# How to check in what page you are? [HTML]

Tags: html

*edit:
I'm working with Single Page Aplication, and by using "ui-route" I manage to go threw my different HTML pages without loading new pages.
So I dont need to include the main page code in every other page.
I hope my question is more understandable now.

I have this main page:
[image]

but when I go to another page I want the logo and the menu apear but not the quote
[image]

Here is the main page code:

```html
<body>
 <div style="text-align: center">
  <img alt="adminPhoto" src="../Img/admin.png" width="300px"
   height="300px">
 </div>
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#/main"><img alt="Main" src="../Ico/main.png"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#/manageCompanies"><img alt="Manage Companies"
    src="../Ico/companies.png"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#/manageCustomers"><img alt="Manage Customers"
    src="../Ico/customers.png"></a></li>
 </ul>

 <div ui-view></div>

 <div>
  <blockquote style="margin-left: 30%;">
   Welcome Admin!<br /> We welcome you to try out most convenient Admin
  experience.<br /> Designed with the most advanced tools.<br /> Update,
  Delete or Create your Companies and Customers - with only one click!<br />
   <footer>
  <cite>Daniel Liverant</cite>
   </footer>
  </blockquote>
 </div>
</body>
```

What way I should try?

Answer (score 0):

create a header.php or header .html file. In there paste your menu and logo. Then include the page on each other html file.

example below:

**Header.php**

```html
<!-- File 1 header.php -->

<img src=".."/>

<nav>
<ul>
<li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

**Content file**

```html
<?php
include "header.php";
?>

<blockqoute> <!-- or not? -->
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don;t think this is the right way to do so, we're talking about SPA, So I dont want to include the HTML main file in every other page, that's the whole point of the ui-routing and SPA.
hope you understand me, also if you can write in html/Js/angular I dont php at all lol

Comment: @DanielLiverant Please edit your question with the right syntax, Sorry but if you ask something this vague, and after answering start giving more information it's not really working...

Answer (score 0):

The include (or require) statement takes all the text/code/markup that exists in the specified file and copies it into the file that uses the include statement.
Including files is very useful when you want to include the same PHP, HTML, or text on multiple pages of a website.

For PHP create two files:

**header.php**

```
<body>
    <div style="text-align: center">
        <img alt="adminPhoto" src="../Img/admin.png" width="300px"
            height="300px">
    </div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#/main"><img alt="Main" src="../Ico/main.png"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#/manageCompanies"><img alt="Manage Companies"
                src="../Ico/companies.png"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#/manageCustomers"><img alt="Manage Customers"
                src="../Ico/customers.png"></a></li>
    </ul>

    <div ui-view></div>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php include 'header.php';?>
<div>
        <blockquote style="margin-left: 30%;">
            Welcome Admin!<br /> We welcome you to try out most convenient Admin
        experience.<br /> Designed with the most advanced tools.<br /> Update,
        Delete or Create your Companies and Customers - with only one click!<br />
            <footer>
        <cite>Daniel Liverant</cite>
            </footer>
        </blockquote>
    </div>
</body>
```

You can include header.php anywhere in your website.

Comment: Hi friend and thank you for your answer, I answered the guy who commented before you - Im using SPA and ui-routing, please see the edit I added to the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do is to insert the quoate code inside the

```
<div ui-view> -code- </div>
```

and that's all.